# How to Audit with Hibernate Envers in multiple JPA connection

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-envers

My project has two connection for JPA (`firstJpa` and `secondJpa`). I've setup project similar [to this](https://github.com/snicoll-demos/demo-multi-entity-managers). Then I want to audit table/entity in `firstJpa` and write log audit into `secondJpa`.

For now, can Hibernate Envers do this? And how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can have Envers construct its audit tables in a separate schema or database / catalog by specifying the appropriate platform-specific configuration setting.

```
org.hibernate.envers.default_schema
org.hibernate.envers.default_catalog
```

It's important to remember you should only need to specify one of these and it depends on your database platform as to which one you should use.

You can define this configuration in a number of places

- In your `application.yml` or `application.properties` file used by `spring-boot`.
- In your spring application's java config for your `Session` or `EntityManager` factory.
- In a `hibernate.properties` file in the root of your application's class path.